# mysqldump stops before dumping structure

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I've got a batch file running on a Windows server that dumps all my MySQL databases out once a day.
There's about 20 databases on the server and everything works fine except for one database.
The command is set to zip up the resulting dump using gZip. The database in question completes its dump with no errors, but when I open the gz file I can only see the standard mysqldump headers, the 'create database if not exists' line and the 'use xxxx' line.
Then, nothing!

The same command is running on all other databases and outputting correctly, so I assume it must be a problem with the database itself - but it's all running fine and I can export with a GUI tool with no problems.

For reference, the database contains only 12 tables, all InnoDB, and is only about 3.3MB in size. No foreign keys, referential integrity, clever indexes or whatnot. There *are* a couple of simple views in the database and thinking about it, this may be the only one on the server containing views... is there an issue with dumping databases containing views?

The command I'm using to dump is as follows:

```
%mysqldir%\bin\mysqldump.exe 
  --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --databases %%f --opt --quote-names 
  --allow-keywords 
  --complete-insert | %zip%\gzip.exe -9 > %backupdir%\%%f\%%f%fn%.sql.gz
```

Obviously there are some variables in there, but should all be self explanatory.

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if you have the proper permissions to access the database in question?

Check the result code.  There may have been errors in the db.

Comment: This is on a local machine, so I'm actually logging in as root. I'd imagine I do have permissions. Where would I find the result code?